# Add to string until hits length (noobie C# guy)

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to read a text file, break it into a string array, and then compile new strings out of the words, but I don't want it to exceed 120 characters in length.

What I am doing with is making it write PML to create a macro for some software I use, and the text can't exceed 120 characters. To take it even further I need to wrap the 120 characters or less (to the nearest word), string with "BTEXT |the string here|" which is the command.

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int BIGSTRINGLEN = 120;

     string readit = File.ReadAllText("C:\\stringtest.txt");
     string finish = readit.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\t", "");
     string[] seeit = finish.Split(' ');
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(BIGSTRINGLEN);
     foreach(string word in seeit)
     {
          while (builder.Length + " " + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN)
          {
                builder.Append(word)
          }

     }
}
```

Comment: The while line (`while (builder.Length + " " + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN)`) does not compile.

Comment: To make the while line work it should probably be something like: while(builder.Length + 1 + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN).
When debugging your code you will probably figure out why it only contains duplicates of the first word in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an if instead of the while as you will continually append the same word if not!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than read the entire file into memory, you can read it a line at a time. That will reduce your memory requirements and also prevent you having to replace the newlines.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(BIGSTRINGLEN);
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    // clean up the line.
    // Do you really want to replace tabs with nothing?
    // if you want to treat tabs like spaces, change the call to Split
    // and include '\t' in the character array.
    string finish = line.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
    string[] seeit = finish.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string word in seeit)
    {
        if ((builder.Length + word.Length + 1 <= BIGSTRINGLEN)
        {
            if (builder.Length != 0)
                builder.Append(' ');
            builder.Append(word);
        }
        else
        {
            // output line
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
            // and reset the builder
            builder.Length = 0;
        }
    }
}
// and write the last line
if (builder.Length > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

That code is going to fail if a word is longer than `BIGSTRINGLEN`. Long words will end up outputting a blank line. I think you can figure out how to handle that case if it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Moon is right - your `while` loop is not going to work as currently placed.

But that aside, you have some problems in this line

```
while (builder.Length + " " + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN)
```

`builder.Length` and `word.Length` are integers - the number of characters in each word. `" "` is not an integer, it's a string. You can't correctly add `10 + " " + 5`. You *probably* want

```
while (builder.Length + (" ").Length + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN) 

// or 
while (builder.Length + 1 + word.Length <= BIGSTRINGLEN)
```